# Java XML Parser Issue

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I'm trying to write an xml parser but seem to be running into some problems when extracting data from the file. I keep running into a java Null pointer exception at the first time I call get Tag Value:

```
Root Element: integrity_bug_data
Getting Tage Value for: id
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

this is what the file looks like:

```
<bug>
        <fields>
            <field name="ID">test</field>
            <field name="Summary"></field>
            <field name="Customer Importance">Unspecified</field>
            <field name="Development Order">Unspecified</field>
            <field name="Created Date">Mon Mar 05 03:41:46 EST 2012</field>
            <field name="Activity">Production</field>
            <field name="State">Triage</field>
            <field name="Date Closed"/>
            <field name="Date Found">Mon Mar 05 00:00:00 EST 2012</field>
            <field name="Issue Type">Software Report</field>
            <field name="Reason">Triage</field>
            <field name="Description">Subject:</field>
        </fields>
    </bug>
```

and I have wrote (after reading some tutorials) this:

```
 try{
        ArrayList<String> idData = new ArrayList<>(), sumryData = new ArrayList<>(), descpData = new ArrayList<>() ;

            //Load the XML File 
        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        org.w3c.dom.Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new File("./Data.xml"));

        System.out.println("Root Element: "+doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

        NodeList bugList = doc.getElementsByTagName("bug");

        for (int i = 0; i < bugList.getLength(); i++){
            Node nNode = bugList.item(i);


            if(nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                idData.add(getTagValue("id",eElement));
                System.out.print("ID: "+getTagValue("id",eElement));


                String sumry = getTagValue("Summary",eElement);
                System.out.println("NodeList: "+sumry);

                String nstr = sumry.replace("\n", " ");
                String ustr = nstr.replaceAll(":", "");
                nstr = ustr.replace(",", " ");

                sumryData.add(nstr);
                System.out.print("Summary: "+nstr);


                String desc = getTagValue("Description",eElement);
                System.out.println("NodeList: "+desc);

                nstr = desc.replace("\n", " ");
                ustr = nstr.replaceAll(":", "");
                nstr = ustr.replace(",", " ");

                descpData.add(nstr);
                System.out.print("Description: "+nstr);
            }
        }

     public static String getTagValue(String tag, Element eElement){
        System.out.println("Getting Tage Value for: "+tag);
        NodeList n1List = eElement.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getChildNodes();
        Node nValue = (Node) n1List.item(0);
        return nValue.getNodeValue();
    }
```

Could the issue have to do with the 
`<field name"..."></field>`

, as supposed to where I am reading for  `<id>, <summary> etc...`?

Thanks in advance for the help...

Comment: Did you tried getTagValue("id",eElement) with uppercase "ID"?

Comment: tried that doesn't change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to change your getTagValue method to something like this:

```
public static String getTagValue(String tag, Element eElement) {
    System.out.println("Getting Tage Value for: " + tag);
    NodeList n1List = eElement.getElementsByTagName("field");
    for (int i = 0; i < n1List.getLength(); i++) {
        Node nNode = n1List.item(i);
        if (((Element) nNode).getAttribute("name").equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
            return nNode.getTextContent();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if `<bug>` contains no `<id>` element,  or if the `<id>` tag has no child nodes.  You didn't allow for either possibility in `getTagValue()`.

Comment: well they all have <field name="ID">...</field>. How would I parse that?

Comment: would I search for field and then the attribute would be name?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not written what  your problem is I cannot help you with *your* code. But I can help to parse this XML. I'd suggest you to use JAXB for parsing. The only thing you need here is to create class `Bug`:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Bug {
    private Collection<Field> fields;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "cars")
    @XmlElement(name = "car")    
    public Collection<Field> getFields() {
        return fields;
    }
    // other methods....
}


public class Field {
    private Sting name;
    private String text;

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    @XmlValue
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

}
```

Now write code like the following:

```
JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.panpwr.api.model.deployment");
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = ctx.createUnmarshaller();
Data data = (Data)unmarshaller.unmarshal(in); // in is the input stream for XML
// now your instance of data is populated from XML
```

That's it. You are done. This will parse your XML without any problems.